# interactive scatter highlight in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to visualise sensor output in relation to its path.
I plot path as scatter in one figure and some range of signal amplitude in the second figure. I need to visualise (highlight) a path point at which the particular reading was taken.

I started using bokeh as a backend and in general, got very good results with visualisations I need. But I am stuck on this particular interaction.

I would like to have some marker like a vertical line anchored in the middle of the figure. When I move/scroll the amplitude plot (the bottom one), I would like to highlight the point on the path plot where the reading closest to the marker line was taken.

The example code:
(I would like to anchor the marker line and add interaction between the red dot and the vertical line taking an index of the signal, which is not implemented.)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

output_file('interactive_path_sig.html', title="interactive path")

class InteractivePath():
    def __init__(self):
        x = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.5)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x,
                                "y": np.sin(x),
                                "z": np.cos(x)})
        self.source = ColumnDataSource(self.df)

    def plot_path(self):
        plt = figure(title = "Sensor Path")
        plt.scatter(x="x", y="y",source=self.source, 
                    line_color=None, size = 6)
        # TODO implement interaction instead of hard coded index
        index=500    # this is where I think I need to create working callback
        print("x={}, y={}".format(self.df['x'][index], self.df['y'][index]))
        plt.circle(x=self.df['x'][index], y=self.df['y'][index], 
                   fill_color="red", size=15)
        hover = HoverTool()
        hover.tooltips=[("index", "@index"), ("senosr","@z")]
        plt.add_tools(hover)
        return plt

    def plot_signal(self):
        plt = figure(x_range=(450, 550), title="Signal Amplitude")
        plt.line(x="index", y="z", source=self.source, line_color="black", line_width=2)
        # TODO implement interaction instead of hard coded index
        index = 500  # I think this needs emit some singal to other plot
        vline = Span(location=index, dimension='height', line_color='red', line_width=3)
        plt.renderers.extend([vline])
        return plt

    def get_grid(self):
        """ place visualisation in a grid and display"""
        grid = gridplot([[self.plot_path()], [self.plot_signal()]], 
                 sizing_mode='stretch_both',)
        return grid

    def vis_main(self):
        """ use all visualisations"""
        show(self.get_grid())

if __name__=="__main__":
    vis = InteractivePath()
    vis.vis_main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: running the code causes `AttributeError: 'InteractivePath' object has no attribute 'TOOLS'` at `def plot_path(self): plt = figure(tools=self.TOOLS, title = "Sensor Path")`

Comment: Thanks @Trenton_M. The `tools=self.TOOLS` can be safely removed. I edited the code. 
I cut down the working code and missed this one, sorry

Comment: This won't directly resolve your inquiry, but here are some additional visualization resources [PyViz: Python data visualization landscape](https://pyviz.org/index.html), start with the `Overview` section & [holoviews](http://holoviews.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Trenton_M I have looked there, but the project is done mainly in Bokeh. This one is part of a big visualisation. Rewriting it would take to another backend is barely and option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a few pointers:

- I think you'll want both of those plots in the same method because the columndatasource is common between them, and you can set CustomJS behaviors between them if they're in the same scope.
- The `index` that you're using already exists within your `self.df` which will be easier to interact with once it's on your plot, since you can handle it with JS plot behavior instead of going back to a python variable and reloading data.
- Instead of drawing a new glyph for your 'highlighted' point, consider using the 'hover' or 'selected' functionality built in. `hover_color='red'` for example could replace drawing and moving another class of glyph.  If you want to leave statically selected so you can generate a nice report without a mouse in a screenshot, defining a callback using the built-in `selected` property of `ColumnDataSource`

I can post some actual code blocks with more specific examples, but if any of these points is a hard stop for your actual use case, it'll drive solution.

---

Edit:

So I got pretty close using one class method - the issue is being able to edit the second plot from the first method, not the actual change to the `ColumnDataSource` itself.

```
def plot_it(self):
    self.plot_signal = figure(x_range=(450, 550), y_range=(-1, 1), title='signal')
    self.plot_signal.line(x='index', y='z', source=self.source)
    self.plot_signal.segment(x0=500, y0=-2, x1=500, y1=2, source=self.source)

    self.plot_path = figure(title='sensor')
    self.plot_path.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=self.source, hover_color='red')

    jscode='''
    var data = source.data;
    var plot_signal = plot_signal;
    var index = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;
    var xmin = 0;
    var xmax = 0;
    if (index > 0) {
        xmin = index[0] - 50;
        xmax = index[0] + 50;
        plot_signal.x_range.end = xmax;
        plot_signal.x_range.start = xmin;
        plot_signal.change.emit();
    }

    hover_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=self.source, plot_signal=self.plot_signal), code=jscode)
    hover.tooltips = [('index', '@index'), ('sensor', '@z')]
    self.plot_path.add_tools(hover)

def get_grid(self):
    self.plot_it()
    grid = gridplot([[self.plot_path], [self.plot_signal]])
    return grid
```

That should do everything but move the line segment.  I couldn't find the segment naming convention to add `plot_signal.SOMEOBJECT.x0` and `.x1` but it would just get added to the `if (index > 0)` block just like using `index[0]`. I took some of the style options out because I'm transcribing from another computer.

This question on [moving a line segment](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/mouse-vertical-line-on-linked-plots/2449/3) might give you the syntax on the segment JSON object.

Comment: thanks for your reply @rumble_bumbles. 1. As the methods are in a single class, the `ColumnDataSource` is shared for each instance of the plots. 2. You right the `index` is within the DataFrame. I named it as such to have exactly this connotation. I think the `index` should be read in either of the methods and propagated maybe as class variable. 3. The plot of the red point and vline are only for presentation purpose. I expect the highlihtes would be somehow dinamic on the plot. If you have any working code whcih would do the job, please post it up. 
Cheers